# WP8 unauthorized MPNS channel

Tags: ssl, windows-phone-8, https, push, mpns

How to get authorized (https) channel in Visual Studio when creating MPNS chanel for WP8.0?

I have server with installed SSL cert, cert is also published in Windows Store for reserved app name.

I'm executing this line of code with service name identical like in published cert in store

```
new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName, "test.domain.com");
```

I'm unable to receive https chanel and I'm always getting http one.

When app is published as beta in Windows Phone Store and installed on device then it's receiving https channel. Do I need to do any special action in Visual Studio to make it work?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling & reinstalling the app before trying to get a new channel? If you try to get a channel in <24 hours, the OS will return the cached HTTP channel.

Comment: I've tried everything. Uninstall, soft reset, hard reset and nothing seems to work. I've posted this question 4 days ago and I'm still getting http chanel so it's not the cache.